Maximizing Population Density for Hunter-Gatherers
How can we maximize population density for a strictly hunter-gatherer population, considering optimal climate, geography, fauna, and flora while making full use of resources from both land and sea? Historical examples like the Chumash of coastal California or the resource-rich societies of the Pacific Northwest provide valuable starting points, as do steppe and grassland cultures that thrived in different ecological conditions.

You really need to focus this question down. As written it looks more like idle speculation than you having an actual worldbuilding problem.

VTC:Needs More Focus. You're not asking for help solving a specific objective problem. You're asking for an education. That's out of scope. Stack Exchange's sweet spot are questions that need 0.5-2.0 page answers. This could take a book, which is prohibited in the [help/dont-ask].

I think fishing falls under the ‘hunting’ category, so a community on the coast of an ocean teaming with life could maybe sustain large numbers off of fishing alone.

I am no expert but my thoughts are these. (focusing on the food problem of this question)
Hunter gatherer societies are just like agricultural societies in many ways. Both are in the long run working to turn energy from the sun into metabolizable sources of chemical energy. The only difference is hunter gathers dont till the earth and grow their own food nor keep farm animals.
Most way to maximize food production (and thus maximize pop density) will in some way turn back into agriculture or animal-husbandry. For example the natives could herd large groups of cattle like cowboys and kill the excess. Shepherds are an example of this where people lived with the sheep and killed as they had need keeping few males alive but having many females to keep the population up. That said I think this hardly fits the bill of purely hunter gatherer. On the other hand if they try to plant anything on their own that is by definition an early form of agriculture.
If you want to be a purist on this matter the only answer is to either 1) have a people with very low food needs or 2) have naturally growing food sources readily available (ex: have an ocean with many many fish, a forest with lots of fruit, or fields with lots of wild buffalo or the like). In all these cases I suspect the population would still shrink to a smaller amount but it may work. I suspect most groups would subdivide into many smaller tribes that could be more mobile to gather in different areas and hunt different groups. With a high population that means there'd be many many tribes but I think this is more likely than one massive tribe that would easily devour the resources in any spot they stopped at.
If you don't want to be a purist but keep the feel of a non agri society I suggest lots of wildly growing plants that can be seasonally harvested and sometimes replanted (berry bushes and the like), fishing, and essentially cowboys nurturing and protecting large herds of cows or buffalo or sheep or whatever. Keeping most of the civs nomadic will also help keep the feel, though it will make nurturing and harvesting food sources enough to maintain a big pop more difficult so some groups (like the fishers and crafters) will likely need to be more sedentary. Every person walking though isn't a person getting food which contributes to calorie concerns on a larger scale.

Animal husbandry is agriculture.

The answer is simple. There has to be more resources in an area than is needed for the population. So have a natural grove of fruit trees that fruit year around. Or just have so many animals that they could never eat them all. Also a lot of water since hunter gather means minimum of water trapping. The reason why these groups are usually small is because they run out of resources to feed themselves so they die or split off into two groups, or they learn how to do crops and herds which is not where you want to go.

I’d like to suggest a more extreme approach.
The problem is that if any animal or plant is so abundant that it can support a large hunter gatherer population, it’s likely they could figure out how to domesticate and farm it. There comes a point where agriculture is the only way to produce food efficiently enough to support a larger population. Agriculture leads to permanent settlements, which means no more hunter gatherers. So how can we make permanent settlements impossible?
Imagine a tidally locked planet with a habitable terminator zone on the edge of the day and night sides. Now increase the rotation speed slightly to make the day only slightly shorter than the year. This should result in a planet where the habitable terminator zone slowly moves across the surface each year. This will force anyone living on this planet to remain nomadic in order to stay within the habitable zone, thus making permanent settlements impossible.
